# Send arraylist with specific format in volley request params

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

I am sending some key and values in volley request params. I am able to send all the data successfully, however, I want to send one of the ArrayList in this format

```
  params.put("facilities", "facilities=1&facilities=3&facilities=7");
```

I put 1, 3 and 7 as an example This will include the elements that are selected and are in my facilities ArrayList. I have 8 items on the screen and if I select 4 then ArrayList will contain 4 items but how to send in this exact params format? I also tried with the code below but it hasn't worked either

```
 for (int i=0; i<facilitiesList.size(); i++){
                params.put("facilities", facilitiesList.get(i).toString());
            }
```

I want to send all the selected data in that format that I showed on top. Anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT - I select items using the code below

```
private List<Integer> facilitiesList; ///initialization


 private BaseRecyclerAdapter<FacilitiesApi.ApiResponse.Datum, FacilitiesViewHolder> mBaseRecyclerAdapter = new BaseRecyclerAdapter<FacilitiesApi.ApiResponse.Datum, FacilitiesViewHolder>(FacilitiesViewHolder.class, R.layout.layout_list_item_facilities) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final FacilitiesViewHolder viewHolder, final FacilitiesApi.ApiResponse.Datum model, final int position) {
        viewHolder.mCustomCheckBoxFacilities.setText(model.getName());
        if (facilitiesList != null) {
            if (facilitiesList.contains(model.getId())) {
                viewHolder.mCustomCheckBoxFacilities.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewHolder.mCustomCheckBoxFacilities.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        viewHolder.mCustomCheckBoxFacilities.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    facilitiesList.add(Integer.valueOf(model.getId()));
                } else {
                    facilitiesList.remove(Integer.valueOf(model.getId()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: first create that value string from your selected values and then pass it params

Comment: @VivekMishra thankyou for the response, can you please explain how to pass selected values to string as i am new to this thing

Comment: Do you have the selected values with you ?

Comment: The selected values are in the facilities arraylist but i don't know how to get them from the arraylist and put them in the format that required

Comment: Is your facilities list of primitive type or object type ?

Comment: I edited the post, can you please check

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create your request String using for loop and then send it in your request.
You should do something like this.

```
    String facilities="";
    for (int i=0; i<facilitiesList.size(); i++){
          if(i==0){
          facilities=facilities+"facilities="+facilities.get(i);
          }else{
          facilities=facilities+"&facilities="+facilities.get(i);
          }
        }
```

The `i==0` check is required to stop adding & symbol on first position.Try this it should work

Comment: Glad to know but I would recommend you to migrate this code by using stringbuilder instead of using string

Comment: Try it yourself as an exercise

Comment: Sure i will do this